# How to pass the value in image cell in iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, opencv, itext, emgucv

Based on below Part of  code, May i know how to passing the picturebox image in image cell iTextSharp in C# ? kindly advise. thank you

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> img1 = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/" + reader.GetString(11) + ".bmp");
Application.Idle -= new EventHandler(ProcessFrame);
pictureBox1.Image = img1;
```

Shall I use string format ?

```
cell = ImageCell(string.Format("+ img1 +"), 25f, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

ImageCell takes byte[] data, it won't take string.

Here is the entire implementation,

```
// Code resides in your page codebehind, do not confuse with AppLevel, it's just my static class
System.Drawing.Image imgResized = AppLevel.Resize(AppLevel.byteArrayToImage(File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/images/companylogo.jpg"))), 194, 138, RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone);
cell = AppLevel.ImageCell(AppLevel.imageToByteArray(imgResized), 30f, PdfPCell.ALIGN_RIGHT);
table.AddCell(cell);

///Helper methods///

/// <summary>
/// Resizes and rotates an image, keeping the original aspect ratio. Does not dispose the original
/// Image instance.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="image">Image instance</param>
/// <param name="width">desired width</param>
/// <param name="height">desired height</param>
/// <param name="rotateFlipType">desired RotateFlipType</param>
/// <returns>new resized/rotated Image instance</returns>
public static System.Drawing.Image Resize(System.Drawing.Image image, int width, int height, RotateFlipType rotateFlipType)
{
    // clone the Image instance, since we don't want to resize the original Image instance
    var rotatedImage = image.Clone() as System.Drawing.Image;
    rotatedImage.RotateFlip(rotateFlipType);
    var newSize = CalculateResizedDimensions(rotatedImage, width, height);

    var resizedImage = new Bitmap(newSize.Width, newSize.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    resizedImage.SetResolution(72, 72);

    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(resizedImage))
    {
        // set parameters to create a high-quality thumbnail
        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

        // use an image attribute in order to remove the black/gray border around image after resize
        // (most obvious on white images), see this post for more information:
        // http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/imgresizoutperfgdiplus.aspx
        using (var attribute = new ImageAttributes())
        {
            attribute.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);

                   // draws the resized image to the bitmap
                   graphics.DrawImage(rotatedImage, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), newSize), 0, 0, rotatedImage.Width, rotatedImage.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attribute);
               }
           }

           return resizedImage;
       }

public static System.Drawing.Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
            System.Drawing.Image returnImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
eturnImage;
            }
```